# Is the new pipe symbol not working in r studio

Tags: r, rstudio

This is my code

```
 Jan.1 <- flights |> 
  filter(month == 1, day == 1)
Jan.1
```

and I keep running in to this error "Error: unexpected '>' in "Jan.1 <- flights |>"
Please Help

Comment: More that you have a version of R that predates the implementation of `|>` (v4.1.0+)

Comment: i would suggest to use the pipe operater used in the `tidyverse` `%>%` since you use dplyr functions anyway

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.